# Problem with Blackberry RIM Signature Tool

Tags: blackberry, signaturetool

I have some COD files that I have developed using the Widget toolkit for Visual Studio.  These COD files need to be signed before I can use them on a device.

When I open the Signature Tool from within Eclipse (3.4.0) every COD file from the current workspace is shown in the list.  If I hit the 'Add' button and select the COD file I want to sign from another location the COD file isn't being listed with all of the other files.

I tried running the Signature Tool from the command line and the same thing happens.  I hit Add, select the COD file and then nothing happens.  If I specify the COD file on the command line then I get an error saying that the Signature Tool can't find any COD files.

The only exception to this was today, just before I went for lunch.  When I clicked Add and selected the COD file it appeared in the list and I could sign it as expected but every other time I've tried it doesn't work.

Any suggestions as to what is happening or any other approaches I can take?

Comment: I hate the COD signing app. I've had trouble like this almost every time I've tried to use it. Never quite figured out why.

Comment: @Ben S - tell me about it!  It worked once, then I locked my computer and went for lunch, when I came back and tried to sign the same project with a small change it didn't work! wtf??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the generated .csl and .cso file was not present in the same directory so the signature tool wasn't aware of which API's needed signed.

Comment: hey Fermin, you might want to go ahead and accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

We use the [BlackBerry Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/) for signing from the command line and it works great.  All it does it launch the actual RIM signing tool but it takes care of passing in the correct list of files and (optionally) your signing password - so it can be more or less automated.  I haven't encountered problems with it other than the odd time when RIM's signing servers are down.

Comment: I've manually ran it from the command line and the signing tool dialog box comes up but when I try to Add my COD files I see a progress bar but they don't appear in the dialog box for signing.